# How to schedule jobs in Jenkins every 3 hours

Tags: jenkins, cron

How can I schedule a Jenkins job to run every 3 hours between `0900` hours and `2100` hours every day?

I tried:

```
0 9-21/3 * *
```

but it gave me an error:

```
Invalid input: "0 9-21/3 * *": line 1:13: expecting space, found 'null'"
```

Comment: You need another `*` at the end.

Comment: That error message could be a lot more helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing this should work.
`0 9-21/3 * * *`

But to avoid the errors & then the warning about "spreading the load evenly" use this.
`H 09-12/3 * * *`